# Need sql query for recent status

Tags: mysql

Here is how my database looks:

```
||  order  ||  ||  status  ||   ||  employees ||
==========     ==============   ===============
id             id               id
name           current_status   display_name
created_by     date(timestamp)  
date           updated_by
```

What I want is for every order, the order details and the latest status:

```
order.id // == status.id
order.name 
order.date
order.created_by // = employees.id
status.current_status //latest status MAX(date)
employees.display_name //status.upated_by = employees.id
```

Here is some sample data:

```
==================================================================
||    order                                     ||
==================================================================
|| id      ||     ||  name   ||   ||  created_by ||  ||  date   ||
==================================================================
5487       ||     ||  Josh   ||   ||  1         ||  ||  2013-24-05
5488       ||     ||  Kren   ||   ||  3         ||  ||  2013-22-04

====================================================================
||          status                                               ||
===================================================================
||   id    ||     ||current_status ||  || date     || || updated_by
===================================================================
||  5487   ||     || Packaged      ||  || 2013-24-05 22-09 || 2
||  5488   ||     || Packaged      ||  || 2013-25-05 12-05 || 3
||  5487   ||     || Shipped       ||  || 2013-28-05 16-05 || 1

===================================================================
||             employees                                        ||
==================================================================
||       id       ||    ||      display_name                ||
===================================================================
|| 1              ||    ||   Rick                               ||
|| 2              ||    ||   Dave                               ||
|| 3              ||    ||   Sydney                             ||
```

This is what I tried but the current_status isn't right:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.created_by, a.date, b.current_status, c.display_name 
FROM id a INNER JOIN ( SELECT id, current_status, MAX(date) FROM status GROUP BY id) b 
ON b.id=a.id INNER JOIN users c ON b.updated_by=c.id AND a.created_by = c.id 
GROUP BY a.id
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: What have you tried so far that isn't working? This looks like a pretty basic `JOIN` with a sub-select for the latest `curent_status`. Please [edit] to include some sample data from each table, the output you want based on that sample data, and some sort of effort to write the query yourself, even if it doesn't include the sub-select for the status.

Comment: I can't figure out from this schema description how statuses are associated with their orders. Do they share the same ID?

Comment: if order.id = status.id then why do not you merge those two tables?

Comment: Every order can have serveral stauses and different employees updating the status.

Comment: This is what I currently have `SELECT a.id, a.name, a.created_by, a.date, b.current_status, c.display_name FROM id a INNER JOIN ( SELECT id, current_status, MAX(date) FROM status GROUP BY id) b ON b.id=a.id INNER JOIN employees c ON created_by=c.id GROUP BY a.id`

Comment: Your question is rather confusing as it is, could you use [**Edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17354837/edit) and properly post your tables separated from each other, as well as what you have tried so far and a sample of the desired output ?

Comment: Please include what you have tried in your question. Don't let it stay at a comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to have sub-query to get the latest status. I believe joining all three tables with a where clause to only include max(date) should do the trick.

```
SELECT * FROM orders o 
  JOIN status st ON o.id=st.id 
  JOIN employees em ON o.created_by = em.id 
 WHERE st.date = (
       SELECT max(date) 
         FROM status 
        WHERE id=st.id 
        GROUP BY id
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach without correlated subquery

```
SELECT o.id, o.name, o.date, o.created_by, z.current_status, e.display_name updated_by
  FROM orders o LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT s.id, s.current_status, s.updated_by
      FROM status s JOIN
    (
        SELECT id, MAX(date) date
          FROM status
         GROUP BY id
    ) q ON s.id = q.id AND s.date = q.date
) z ON o.id = z.id JOIN employees e 
    ON z.updated_by = e.id
```

Output:

```
|   ID | NAME |       DATE | CREATED_BY | CURRENT_STATUS | UPDATED_BY |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 5487 | Josh | 2013-05-24 |          1 |        Shipped |       Rick |
| 5488 | Kren | 2013-04-22 |          3 |       Packaged |     Sydney |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e159/5)** demo